# Adding "toJSON" method a JavaScript object instance causes Maximum Callstack error

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-5

I wanted to add a `.toJson` method to an instantiated JavaScript object, which would allow me to get the stringified object instance without functions and prototype, to transmit during a request.

However, it seems like the actual name of the function 'toJSON' as a method name impacts the ability of JavaScript engine (at least in V8) to run the function - that is, if you rename the same exact function to "JSON" instead of "toJSON", it works, however, as "toJSON", it causes a Maximum Callstack error. See example:

```
function P1(name, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age= age;
    this.toJSON = function(){
        return JSON.stringify(this);
    }
}

function P2(name, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age= age;
    this.JSON = function(){
        return JSON.stringify(this);
    }
}

// This causes an error: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded(…)
var p1 = new P1('Memory Error', 10);
try {
  p1.toJSON();
} catch(e){
    console.log(e);
}

var p2 = new P2('No Error', 20);
p2.JSON();
```

Is this an expected behavior of JavaScript? Does it have something to do with "toJSON" being a native method (note: I have verified that on an instantiated object as above, there is no toJSON method on the prototype that would interfere with a redefinition on the instance)? I am trying to determine if I should report this as a bug to V8 team, or this is explainable by someone who knows more about the spec.

Thanks

Comment: `JSON.stringify` calls the object's `toJSON` method.  This calls `JSON.stringify` which calls `toJSON` which calls `JSON.stringify`...

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` will call the `toJSON()` function defined on your object.  Hopefully you can see why you have the problem...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not what the `.toJSON` method is used for.  You use `.toJSON` to *override* the default stringification behavior.  The `.toJSON` is called *internally* by `JSON.stringify`, you don't need to call it on your own.  `.toJSON` can return a string, object, array, whatever you want to be stringified in the response from `JSON.stringify`.

Your `.toJSON` method needs to do something other than call `JSON.stringify(this)`.  Right now you are getting an infinite loop since `JSON.stringify(this)` calls the object's `.toJSON`, and so on.

Try something like this:

```
function P1(name, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age= age;
    this.toJSON = function(){
        return {
            name: this.name,
            age: this.age
        };
    }
}

var p1 = new P1('Test', 10);
console.log(JSON.stringify(p1));
```

Comment: Very cool - I did not know that JSON.stringify fn's behavior was to first try to call the toJSON method of the object it was stringifying! I assumed it just involved the procedure of stripping out functions and prototype properties and converting the rest into a string. Thanks, cheers!

Comment: There's more info on MDN's page about `JSON.stringify()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify :-)